# Getting Microsoft.Web.Services3 available for VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010 and I am making a call to a vendor's web service, which they use WSE i web services. I can not find in "Add references" to add the namespace/dll. It works when i created a project in VS2005.
I Found this blog and it indicated on how to get it recognized.
http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/how-to-use-wse-3-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx
but after trying that it still doesn't work for me. Anyone have any ideas for me?

Thanks,
Marios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to fix this is to generate the Webservice in Visual Studio 2005 then copy the code into just a class in VS2010 and use it as a class instead as a Webservice. It's not the best wey for keeping things standard but it works flawlessly!

Comment: -1: I would argue that it's a flaw to use obsolete software (WSE) when there's a good chance that "Add Service Reference" would have "just worked". Did you try that?

Comment: It is not my software to argue that they shouldn't use WSE. it makes no sense to set my answer -1 when I can't control how a vendor operates. I tried creating a service reference, that is why I posted this. It did generate the object but not fully, it did not create the correct object to call it with their WSE methods.

Comment: Then that's the problem you should ask about. There may very well be a better solution than using WSE on the client side. You may very well be able to use WCF on the client side, which removes half of the obsolete software from the picture.

Comment: +1 for a real world answer. Sometimes you don't have a choice but to do the dirty

Comment: What if you don't have VS2005?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by downloading the WSE Runtime from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6545)

Answer (score 3):

For me, even after adding the reference to the local copy of **Microsoft.Web.Service3.dll**, I still had to change the project to be geared for **.NET 4.0** and not **.NET 4.0 Client**.

**Microsoft.Web.Service3.dll** has a dependency on **System.Web**, which doesn't exist in the **.NET 4.0 Client**, but does in **.NET 4.0**.

This factoid was noted in the Error List, in the Warnings.
Only the fact that the **Microsoft.Web** namescape could not be found was in the Errors.

-Jesse

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem when used SAP Business object dlls.
I installed WSE from (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en) and added reference to my project.
It solved the issue